# ¿Cómo leer dos string con Scanner en java?

Tags: java, string, consola, scanner

Tengo un problema utilizando la clase scanner de java para recibir dos valores string por consola, tengo lo siguiente:

```
switch(op){
            case 1:
                // Creacion y declaracion de variables
                int codigo = r.nextInt(9999 - 1000);
                System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del producto: ");
                String nombre = entrada.nextLine();
                entrada.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese la descripción del producto: ");
                String descrip = entrada.nextLine();
                int precioVenta = r.nextInt(30000 - 5000 + 1) + 5000;
                int precioCompra = r.nextInt(18000 - 1500 + 1) + 1500;
                int cantidad = r.nextInt(50 - 1 + 1) + 1;

                Producto producto = new Producto(codigo,nombre,descrip,precioVenta,precioCompra,cantidad);
                obj.AgregarProducto(producto);
                break;
```

Al correr el programa y mostrar el objeto obtenido, me muestra todo menos el nombre, eso me lo deja en blanco, como podran ver en la siguiente imagen:

[image: El nombre deberia ir entre el primer numero y el string que ahí aparece]

estuve buscando en la web y recomendaban colocar "entrada.nextLine()" antes de leer un dato string pero no entendí el por qué y además ahora si me lee los dos pero me elimina uno.

Comment: Los valores se insertan uno a uno o los dos de una vez?

Comment: Se insertan uno a uno

Comment: El código está bien, solo `entrada.nextLine();` está de más. Puede ser que el problema esté en otro lugar, tal vez en el constructor de clase `Producto`.

Comment: si, está de mas `entrada.nextLine();`, eso se hace para limpiar el scanner, pero cuando usas varios tipos de datos, y solo estas usando String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La cuestión estaba como decian los comentarios en "entrada.nextLine()" sin embargo, la solución de quitar esa linea no me sirvió, sino que debia ir pero en otra posición, asi como muestro en el código final:

```
// Creacion y declaracion de variables
                    int codigo = r.nextInt(9999 - 1000);
                    entrada.nextLine();   // <-- AQUI SE LEE EL SALTO DE LINEA DESPUES 
                                          //  DEL DATO ENTERO PARA QUE LA SIGUIENTE LINEA SEA EL STRING
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del producto: ");
                    String nombre = entrada.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Ingrese la descripción del producto: ");
                    String descrip = entrada.nextLine();
                    int precioVenta = r.nextInt(30000 - 5000 + 1) + 5000;
                    int precioCompra = r.nextInt(18000 - 1500 + 1) + 1500;
                    int cantidad = r.nextInt(50 - 1 + 1) + 1;
```